# Emacs Lisp error: (void-variable Alias)

Tags: debugging

How can I figure out where the problem exists from the following Emacs Error?

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable Alias)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-879707> nil "/home/hagbard/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0/typex/galex/protex/protex.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 4970
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/hagbard/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0/typex/galex/protex/protex.el" "/home/hagbard/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0/typex/galex/protex/protex.el" nil t)
  require(protex)
  galex-protex(go)
  galex-ignition()
  (progn (galex-ignition))
  (if (eq 'go actn) (progn (galex-ignition)))
  marshal-galex(go)
  marshal-launch()
  (progn (marshal-launch))
  (if (eq 'go actm) (progn (marshal-launch)))
  typex-marshal(go)
  typex-launch-tools()
  (if (equal statck 'nogo) nil (add-to-list 'load-path "~/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0/typex/") (load "typex") (typex-launch-tools))
  gungadin-typex-launch(go)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/hagbard/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2823
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/hagbard/.emacs" "/home/hagbard/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x43aebc48e671cb4>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c6feddc0d0e75>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Show the code in file `/home/hagbard/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0/typex/galex/protex/protex.el`.

Comment: It is unfortunate that the Debugger does not strive to show a line number as I can do in fortran.

Comment: An errant `)` was causing the problem.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: "It is unfortunate that the debugger does not ... show a line number" - it does much better than that: it shows you the exact position in the buffer - scroll to the right and you'll see `Reading at buffer position 4970`.